# Mounted Volumes for IBM Bluemix CF Apps

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, mount-point, shared-data

IBM Containers on Bluemix has the support for mounting volumes and use across containers. Is there any way we can have a similar shared volumes kind w.r.t Bluemix CF Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Foundry applications on IBM Bluemix can use [Bluemix's Object Storage service](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/dashboard/storage) for shared storage between applications.

Cloud Foundry does not support sharing volumes across instances and [discourages users from writing the the filesystem as storage](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem).

Using Object Storage, you have an API to access and share files between applications.